# 2 vertically positioned divs, what could prevent them from "touching?"

Tags: css, html, margin

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/FBX6Y/) to see what I mean.. What could prevent these two from sitting directly atop each other like that. At the moment on my site I have to use `margin-bottom:-22px;` to get the effect.

And of course, it doesn't work in IE...

Thanks :)

Comment: What browser are you using? They look like they're sitting on top of each other to me.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question correctly?
Why don't you put a positive margin-top at your second div ?

Comment: On the page you linked to I just added margin-bottom:1em; to #one to fix it.

Comment: SOrry, I thin I've misspoken, I want this effect, but on my site it doesn't work, but the code is the same (but the example is simplified) I was just wondering what could prevent this from happening?

Comment: can you give a link to you site we could have a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some inherited margin, perhaps? It's very hard to know without the context.

A useful tool to identify problems of this type is what is known in most browsers as "developer tools" (Firebug in Firefox). Right click on any element and choose `Inspect element` in order to easily view the box model of any element, and from where it has acquired those styles.

Here's some links on how to do this with Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/layout and http://getfirebug.com/css

Comment: Yeah, using firebug, have applid margin 0 to both elements, nothing in firebug and nothing else I can see that's inherited. Maybe it's internal browser styles. But I doubt that.

Comment: Well it was that the height had been set to 3em and was oversized. I was looking for the wrong attribute, accepting this answer as found the problem with Firebug. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a margin defined somewhere, either in the internal browser styles or elsewhere in your stylesheet? Try setting the margin to 0 on both elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using a positive margin value should result in them being spaced further apart

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? If you add `margin-top: 2px` to the bottom div, it will appear 2px further down, i.e. not touching. Is there a problem with this...?